# messages in nextjs are not setting up with socket io

Tags: reactjs, next.js, socket.io, socket.io-client

i'm trying to create a simple chat. i made a customhook to handle connection with socket io

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

export type Message = {
  author: string;
  msg: string;
};

export const useChatSocket = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/socket');

    const newSocket = io();

    setSocket(newSocket);
    newSocket.on('message', (message) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
    });

    return () => {
      newSocket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (message: Message) => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.emit('sendMessage', message);
      setMessages((currentMessages) => [...currentMessages, message]);
    }
  };

  return { messages, sendMessage };
};
```

i did it to re-use in another applications, seens work but i'm not sure

my chat component is this

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import * as Styled from './styles';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { Heading } from '../Heading';
import { Input } from '../Input';
import { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { useChatSocket } from '@/customHooks/useChatSocket';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';

export const Chat = () => {
  const { messages, sendMessage } = useChatSocket();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!message) return;

    const newMessage = {
      author: session?.user?.name || 'Nome Padrão',
      msg: message,
    };

    sendMessage(newMessage);

    setMessage('');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Styled.Wrapper>
        {messages.map((message) => {
          const isMe = message.author === session?.user?.name;
          const showHeading = !isMe;
          return (
            <Styled.Message key={uuid()} isMe={isMe}>
              {showHeading && <Heading as={'h5'}>{message.author}</Heading>}
              {message.msg}
            </Styled.Message>
          );
        })}
      </Styled.Wrapper>
      <Styled.Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          margin={'5px 0px 5px 5px'}
          height={'35px'}
          placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          id="message"
          value={message}
        />
        <Styled.Button>
          <SendIcon fontSize="inherit" />
        </Styled.Button>
      </Styled.Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

just a simple chat component.
and my handle is

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const ioHandler = (req, res) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) return res.end();
  const io = new Server(res.socket.server, { path: 'api/socket' });
  res.socket.server.io = io;
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('sendMessage', (message) => {
      io.emit('message', message);
    });
  });
};

export default ioHandler;
```

but to be honest, i'm learning and i dont really know what i'm doing wrong . the error is that if i open the app in another tab, the messages dont mix... maybe the connection are wrong? i tried pass the path in the io('localhost:3000/api/socket') but dont work ... using the fetch my console.log() are displayed at least